# Make a child overflow div resize its parent properly

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div, and two children. 
The first is a bar (with buttons) that should always stay at the top.
The other is a content-editable `div`, and should be allowed to resize with its parent "shrink wrapping" around it.

The scrollbar must be in the bottom `div`, not the parent, so I don't think that setting `overflow` and `resize` for the parent is acceptable.

Also, if I set a border radius on the parent or children, the scrollbar and resize scrubber cuts off a corner.

I need to also be able to specify a default width and height for the parent and still allow it to be resized smaller and larger if the user decides.

I have created a JS fiddle to show my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/spikespaz/6jvu1xnd/1/

And the code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
}

.bar {
  background: #000;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="bar">
  <!-- Top bar above the text entry / contenteditable div
  In practice, this will be a list with buttons. -->
  </div>
  <div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc magna dui, facilisis a lectus non, auctor ultrices felis. Phasellus auctor auctor sem at blandit. Ut in metus euismod, sodales diam non, pretium neque. Praesent lectus tortor, ullamcorper at gravida in, lobortis sit amet enim. Aliquam feugiat euismod ligula. Phasellus maximus nunc ut tellus mollis laoreet. Fusce id fermentum lectus.</p>
    <p>In a posuere mi, tempor laoreet elit. Sed non tristique ligula. Morbi a condimentum tellus. Vestibulum blandit, orci sed sagittis mollis, purus quam iaculis metus, quis tincidunt leo ligula sit amet magna. Donec tempor nisl diam, nec pellentesque lorem vulputate vel. In augue dui, dapibus et ipsum sed, blandit aliquam dolor. Donec non arcu non est ullamcorper lacinia. Sed egestas dictum orci, tincidunt facilisis odio aliquam nec.</p>
    <p>Duis vitae arcu gravida, vestibulum leo quis, auctor ligula. Sed eleifend mi ut neque egestas elementum. Praesent elit nisl, rutrum sit amet tellus sed, dapibus interdum nulla. Suspendisse efficitur semper ullamcorper. Ut ac viverra augue. Maecenas pharetra rhoncus nulla, et cursus leo luctus et. Ut molestie quam ex, id mattis turpis tincidunt quis. Integer cursus efficitur cursus. Etiam ullamcorper lacinia efficitur. Nunc a sem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse dapibus massa sem, et cursus velit luctus quis. Nulla quis semper lacus. Integer fermentum odio eget ipsum luctus, sit amet suscipit sapien commodo. Vestibulum vitae finibus leo, et pretium tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu scelerisque sem. Mauris accumsan condimentum felis ac aliquam. Fusce efficitur nec mauris id pharetra. Curabitur pulvinar nulla urna, vitae tempus lorem ultricies sed. Curabitur malesuada, purus sed tempor maximus, lacus ligula auctor turpis, venenatis consequat mauris ex non nibh. Nam ac commodo leo, lacinia sagittis ligula. Phasellus non sodales est, in convallis libero. Donec nisl neque, dignissim vitae fringilla in, congue a nunc. Nulla mollis, sapien quis venenatis vulputate, ligula velit pellentesque risus, ultricies imperdiet lectus mauris vel est.</p>
    <p>Ut consequat semper nisi, sed varius sem posuere in. Donec egestas orci vitae sem bibendum congue. Pellentesque venenatis non erat egestas feugiat. Phasellus volutpat, tortor sed convallis pulvinar, sem elit suscipit erat, et commodo risus nulla vitae eros. Etiam sollicitudin ipsum ac nisi gravida, sit amet ultrices purus efficitur. Aliquam egestas ac arcu et mattis. Nulla volutpat arcu sed mattis ornare.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make the three `div`s behave like I want them to?

**Edit:** Also, it should be noted that I am trying to avoid using JS in any form to do this. I would prefer not to add that overhead if it can be done another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
  .parent {
  width: 80%;
  height : 300px;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  margin : 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  background: #000;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
      overflow: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: calc(100% - 40px);
}


<div class="parent">
  <div class="bar">
  </div>
  <div class="content" contenteditable="true">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc magna dui, facilisis a lectus non, auctor ultrices felis. Phasellus auctor auctor sem at blandit. Ut in metus euismod, sodales diam non, pretium neque. Praesent lectus tortor, ullamcorper at gravida in, lobortis sit amet enim. Aliquam feugiat euismod ligula. Phasellus maximus nunc ut tellus mollis laoreet. Fusce id fermentum lectus.</p>
    <p>In a posuere mi, tempor laoreet elit. Sed non tristique ligula. Morbi a condimentum tellus. Vestibulum blandit, orci sed sagittis mollis, purus quam iaculis metus, quis tincidunt leo ligula sit amet magna. Donec tempor nisl diam, nec pellentesque lorem vulputate vel. In augue dui, dapibus et ipsum sed, blandit aliquam dolor. Donec non arcu non est ullamcorper lacinia. Sed egestas dictum orci, tincidunt facilisis odio aliquam nec.</p>
    <p>Duis vitae arcu gravida, vestibulum leo quis, auctor ligula. Sed eleifend mi ut neque egestas elementum. Praesent elit nisl, rutrum sit amet tellus sed, dapibus interdum nulla. Suspendisse efficitur semper ullamcorper. Ut ac viverra augue. Maecenas pharetra rhoncus nulla, et cursus leo luctus et. Ut molestie quam ex, id mattis turpis tincidunt quis. Integer cursus efficitur cursus. Etiam ullamcorper lacinia efficitur. Nunc a sem ipsum.</p>
    <p>Suspendisse dapibus massa sem, et cursus velit luctus quis. Nulla quis semper lacus. Integer fermentum odio eget ipsum luctus, sit amet suscipit sapien commodo. Vestibulum vitae finibus leo, et pretium tellus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu scelerisque sem. Mauris accumsan condimentum felis ac aliquam. Fusce efficitur nec mauris id pharetra. Curabitur pulvinar nulla urna, vitae tempus lorem ultricies sed. Curabitur malesuada, purus sed tempor maximus, lacus ligula auctor turpis, venenatis consequat mauris ex non nibh. Nam ac commodo leo, lacinia sagittis ligula. Phasellus non sodales est, in convallis libero. Donec nisl neque, dignissim vitae fringilla in, congue a nunc. Nulla mollis, sapien quis venenatis vulputate, ligula velit pellentesque risus, ultricies imperdiet lectus mauris vel est.</p>
    <p>Ut consequat semper nisi, sed varius sem posuere in. Donec egestas orci vitae sem bibendum congue. Pellentesque venenatis non erat egestas feugiat. Phasellus volutpat, tortor sed convallis pulvinar, sem elit suscipit erat, et commodo risus nulla vitae eros. Etiam sollicitudin ipsum ac nisi gravida, sit amet ultrices purus efficitur. Aliquam egestas ac arcu et mattis. Nulla volutpat arcu sed mattis ornare.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On `.content` height cannot be hardcoded, it must be relative to what `.parent` is.

Comment: Do you want the scrollbar on the content div instead of parent keeping everything same?

Comment: Yes, I want the outer div to contain the toolbar and the content editor, and have a border. It needs to be resize and scroll-able, and the sizing needs to look normal.

Comment: I have update the answer. It has all the things you need plus its responsive.

Comment: It looks good, except if I add a `resize: both;` to the content editable div it goes out of "bounds".

Comment: I guess you can handle that with javascript or jquery when .content is resized, you can get the width and assign it to parent.